# How can I set a variable in a long one liner using a windows cmdline?

Tags: windows, batch-file

For example:

I want to set a variable and then have it output on the same line.

set /p MESSAGE= && echo %MESSAGE%

But it doesn't quite work like you expect. Is there a way to pipe it to echo or is there a better way to delimit separate commands?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot work the way you try here since environment variables are expanded while *parsing* a line, not when executing it. Since `%MESSAGE%` is only meaningful *after* executing the first part, this cannot work.

This however will:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p MESSAGE= && echo !MESSAGE!
```

See `help set` for a discussion of delayed expansion.

Comment: For some reason, this does not work when typed in in cmd directly

Comment: @Lekensteyn: Start `cmd` with `cmd /v:on` to enable delayed expansion. `setlocal` is for batch files, just as is `goto`. They have no effect in the interactive command line.